# Finding observations by minimum distance in QGIS

Tags: qgis, vector, distance, features, proximity

I am trying to look at the distance between property sales and crimes committed within city. I want to be able to find all the crime that occurs within 1 mile of each property sold. I am sure that is fairly easy but I can't figure out how to do it.

Also, I don't want to have 50 different crimes with 50 different distances reported for the same house on 50 different rows. I want to see if I can get the total of each unique crime committed on the same row of the property sold, along with the average distance to all the crimes committed within 1 mile of that property.

Comment: Do you have the crime and property data?  https://dges.carleton.ca/CUOSGwiki/index.php/Analyzing_Crime_Data_in_Ottawa_using_QGIS

Comment: I have already collected the data for both crime and property data, and they are both shapefiles

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve this using a ["Virtual Layer"](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/managing_data_source/create_layers.html#creating-virtual-layers).

Go to the menu `Layer > Add Layer > Add/Edit Virtual Layer...` and enter the following query. Adjust the layer and field names.

Remember that virtual layers are computed in memory, so feel free to export it to another format if needed.

```sql
SELECT
    a.*, --all fields from the property layer
    avg(ST_Distance(a.geometry, b.geometry)) as average_dist,
    count(b.id) as nb_crime
FROM
    myPropertyLayer a
LEFT JOIN
    myCrimeLayer b
    ON ST_Distance(a.geometry, b.geometry) < 5000
GROUP BY a.id
```

Answer (score 2):

Using QGIS expressions, this is the expression to get the number of crimes within a maximum distance of 1000 from each property:

```
array_length(
    overlay_nearest(
        'crime',  -- change layer name
        $id,
        max_distance:=1000, --change distance
        limit:=-1
    )
)
```

To get the mean distance of all crime sites within a maximum radius of 1000 from each property, use this expression:

```
array_mean(
    array_foreach(
        overlay_nearest(
            'crime',  -- change layer name
            $geometry,
            max_distance:=1000,  -- change distance
            limit:=-1
        ),
        length(make_line($geometry, @element))
    )
)
```